# Are there any good resources to learn mathematical analysis of single player games and puzzles?

Tags: algorithmic-game-theory

What are the best resources to understand the mathematical analysis of single player games like Solitaire, Free Cell, Sudoku, Rubik's Cube, etc.? Most game theory books I browsed in the local book store seem to deal predominantly with multiplayer games, and have very limited coverage of single player games and puzzles.